# Are all of the popular bundles of Symfony 3 compatible with Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm starting a new project with Symfony and I was wondering if I should use Symfony 4 or 3.4 considering the fact that Symfony 4 has a lot of changes and new mindset.

So, if I use Symfony 4 will all the popular bundles (FOS...etc) be compatible with Symfony 4? Also has anyone faced any compatibility issue when using Symfony 4 compared to 3.4?

Answer (score 1):

You can still find most of those libraries (bundles) on the Symfony's **recipes** server, you can look for your current libraries to check if they were moved to Symfony 4 or not:

https://symfony.sh/

And check the Github repo if you want to learn more about Recipes :

https://github.com/symfony/recipes

Comment: Do you have any idea on what's different between a bundle and a recipe? Like what's new and what's changed and what to do if a bundle isn't in the recipes list.

Comment: Fabian potencier has all the answers you need in his posts in medium where he discusses the Symfony 4 new features, here's one of his posts that may answer your questions : https://medium.com/@fabpot/symfony-4-monolith-vs-micro-52dc6b98c0c5

Comment: This answer is so wrong it's not even funny.  Yes, Symfony still has plenty of bundles including the all important FrameworkBundle.  Recipes merely make configuring the bundles a tiny bit easier.

Comment: Even if the name still included bundle, now it's a composer package :) still so funny !

Comment: No.  Just no.  You should perhaps familiarize yourself with the Symfony framework.  Might be surprised at what you might discover. https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html  And while bundles are often delivered as composer packages, bundles are still a completely different concept.